# Calling another PHP script in AJAX success callback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST"
   , url: "first-script.php"
   , data: {
      dataPoint: dataValue
   }
   , success: function (dataPath) {
      // Do stuff with dataPath

      // Call another PHP script once done.
   }
 });
```

I am stuck at the `Call another PHP script once done.` part. How can I do that? Is it possible at all? Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Another ajax request?

Comment: just add another Ajax request that's all

Comment: @RossWilson Do I just need to nest the requests?

Comment: @SarathKumar Should I add the AJAX request inside the success callback?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it :)

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks. It worked. Nesting the requests seemed a bit odd though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the ajax with previous ajax request success call back:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "first-script.php",
data: {
        dataPoint: dataValue
     },
success: function (dataPath) {
  //Another request
  $.ajax({});
});
```